# Как остановить function

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#test").click( function(){
            test(0,20);
        });
        $("#stop").click( function(){
            // как остановить test();
        });
    });

    test = function (i,max){
        if(i <= max){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'in.php',
                data: {x:'user'},
                dataType: "text",
                cache: false,
                success: function(dat) {
                    console.log(i);
                    test(i+1,max);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Таким образом остановить не получится, т.к. нет условий для выхода, которыми можно управлять извне.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант завести глобальную переменную (или переменную в объекте test) по значению которой будет вызываться функция test или нет. В событии где надо остановить, просто изменять это значение.

```
$("#stop").click( function(){
    stopFun = true;
    // как остановить test();
});

success: function(dat) {
    console.log(i);
    if (!stopFun) {test(i+1,max)};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $ajaxObj = null;
var stop = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").click( function(){
        test(0,20);
    });
    $("#stop").click( function(){
        $ajaxObj.abort();
        stop = true;
    });
});

test = function (i,max){
    if(i <= max && !stop){
        $ajaxObj = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'in.php',
            data: {x:'user'},
            dataType: "text",
            cache: false,
            success: function(dat) {
                console.log(i);
                if(!stop) test(i+1,max);
            }
        });
    }
}
```